# Internet Explorer 11 Delayed Session on Classic ASP with Ajax

Tags: session, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11, session-variables

In testing code which works otherwise correctly within Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

The basic script is to log time spent on a specific article. 
As the page loads, a session variable is set with the datetime the page loaded and a separate one with the ID of the article, on the same page there is a javascript timer which fires an XHR request every 60 seconds to a page which looks at the session variables, and submits to the database every full minute that passes whilst the script is running.

In Internet explorer 11, if you browse to a document, the session is set and can be called on the page, yet when the XHR request is called the session variable is apparently empty.

However, if you browse to an alternate document, this proceeds to show the correct session variable.

Only on the first article visit does the session variable not transfer across to the XHR request.

I have tried checking the SessionID, this appears the same across all pages/requests.

I have tried pre-setting the session variable in the global.asa to make sure the variable container is there at session start, with no difference in behaviour.

I'm not sure where to go from here as this appears to be an IE 11 issue, but know for certain 99% of our users have issued laptops with IE11 as their default browser.

Any help or pointers would be valued.

Comment: Could be a CORS issue that only IE flags, are any warnings logged to the console? Also, posting your JS would be helpful too.

Comment: Have you used F12 to check if there's any error in console in IE? And please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a better understanding of the issue and we can have a test in our sides. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I was ignoring some pretty substantial information within the console, where various pieces of javascript are looking to load information from the server which is not there on the first load within the site. Consequently, these files not found are being served with a page which closes the timer and resets the session variable - this was only happening on the first load, as these files are not checked for again afterwards.
Now to find how to remove all of the references to the missing .less files that the legacy bootstrap code I'm working with has embedded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my particular case, studying the console and seeing that legacy js libraries, such as bootstrap, were calling for items which were not there. Since I have custom Error pages which run the same piece of code to close the timer (and reset the session cookie), the session variables I was looking for were being removed on the 404 page in the background.

This item is now solved.